# Is there a way to correct wrongly typed password / abort the operation while on password prompt in the console in MINGW32?

Tags: terminal, passwords, git, github, mingw

I sometimes mistype a password when being asked for it, e.g. by Git when pushing to remote repository. The password is not displayed (even masked as asterisks) in the console.

Is there a way either to correct the password, or to abort the operation? <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for editing and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> for aborting do not seem to work.

I want to save some time instead of waiting for the remote authentication to fail, or providing a bad password, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

**Edit 2:**

Unfortunately neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> nor <kbd>@</kbd> do not work for me. Any other guesses?

I used MINGW32 bash under Windows XP, but as pointed by @silencedhaven, my terminal shouldn't matter, but rather the one I'm connecting to. So I'm trying to push to GitHub by HTTPS.

Comment: Did is after you press enter? And do you realize that the password is wrong after pressing enter, or because the host is waiting?

Comment: I'm aware of the typo just after pressing wrong key on the keyboard. At that time, I want to fix it, or abort, without pressing `ENTER`. I know I can type `ENTER` and `CTRL`-`C` quickly afterwards.

Comment: Is [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50493/11750) what you're looking for?

Comment: May depend on your terminal type, but `CTRL-U` often does it for me, if I understand your situation.

Comment: Yep it's my case unfortunately. Tried `CTRL` with `U`, `W` and several other buttons and none of it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has been solved in Git 1.8. I can correct my wrongly typed password in Git 1.8.1.2 @ WinXP.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> will erase from the current cursor position back to the beginning of the line, so you can then type your correct password.

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work under my terminal - MINGW32 (Git 1.7.11) @ Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>@</kbd> (usually <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>). In some getty variants, it means *erase to the beginning of line*, basically a do-over. After pressing <kbd>@</kbd>, start typing your password from the beginning.

It all depends on what you are connecting to, not what you are running as a terminal emulator. For the past eight years, I am using PuTTY as my terminal emulator, and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works fine if I am connecting to a RedHat Linux system to erase one character at a time, but when I am connecting to an HPUX system, I have to use <kbd>@</kbd> to start over. So, you need to know how the  keyboard input reading program (getty in most Unix cases) interprets the non-printable characters like, `BKSP`, `DEL`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. However, `@` also doesn't work for me.

Comment: what is the type of system you are trying to connect to ? do you know that ? Because, if you don't, we are chasing a red herring here. The best way to figure this out is to talk to the administrator(s) of the remote system and learn their key-press/keyboard reader executable and what it accepts as del/bksp characters

Comment: In my particular case, I'm trying to push to Github. No idea which Unix flavor they're using.

Comment: since github is a commonly used platform, I'm sure you are not the only one. The problem is, here, on superuser.com, I don't believe there are too many github users. if you pose this question on one of github concentrated/targeted forums, you can get a faster answer. if you wait here long enough, the same answer will eventually come I'm sure.

Comment: Yep I'll try to contact Github support and write here if I solve it.